# jquery scroll only with rel attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, anchor

i have following function:

```
var jump=function(e)
{
   if (e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var target = $(this).attr("href");
   }else{
       var target = location.hash;
   }

   $('html,body').animate(
   {
       scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
   },2000,function()
   {
       location.hash = target;
   });

}

$('html, body').hide();

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('a[href^=#]').bind("click", jump);

    if (location.hash){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('html, body').scrollTop(0).show();
            jump();
        }, 0);
    }else{
        $('html, body').show();
    }
});
```

that permit to scroll to the specific div element

```
<div id="anchor_element">blabla</div>
```

if i click on link :

```
<a href="#anchor_element">Scroll here</a>
```

i want that function above work only if in html link i have included a specific rel attribute for example "myscroll":

```
<a href="#anchor_element" rel="myscroll">Scroll here</a>
```

how to modify function for work in this mode?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('a[href^=#][rel="myscroll"]').bind("click", jump);
```

---

[Has Attribute Selector [name]](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

If you want it to work with all elements with `rel` attribute

```
$('a[href^=#][rel]').bind("click", jump);
```

---

Update

```
$('a[href^=#],a[rel="myscroll"]').bind("click", jump);
           //^ works for both a start with # and with rel="myscroll"
```